# why i cant use category detailview ? if use it get 404 in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I want use category_slug or id_slug for detailview as productdetailview 
and show all of product that category there but i don't know how do that 
i used this views but i get errors 404. why is different between `productdetailview` and `categorydetailview`? could plz help me to solve this problem?

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120,unique=True)



class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category,blank=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    defalut = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name="defalut_category",blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)




   class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.slug})
```

views.py

```
def ProductDetail(request,slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,slug=slug,active=True)
    context = {
        "product":product
    }
    template_name = "product_detail.html"
    return render (request,template_name,context)


def CategoryDetail(request,category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,slug = category_slug)
    product = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        'category':category,
        'product': product
    }
    template_name ="category_detail.html"
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name ='category'

urlpatterns = [
    path('category-list/',views.CategoryList,name="category_list" ),
    re_path(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.CategoryDetail, name='category_detail'),
```

**My error**

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/elctroinc/
>   Raised by:  products.views.CategoryDetail
>   No Category matches the given query.
>   You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Can you add the error traceback as well as your `urls.py` ?

Comment: @JPG i added it .

Comment: when i used category = Category.objects.filter(slug=category_slug) show me that but when i use get objects get 404 .

Comment: did you check `category_slug` is coming correctly and has present in DB?

Comment: The error says that there is no `Category` instance with provided `slug` (the `category_slug`)

Comment: @Manjo Jadhav : yes as i said when i user category.objects.filter i don't get error and see the that but why i can't use get objects or 404 .

Comment: @JPG right now i check that with id and see error goes away or not tnx.

Comment: @JPG i checked that but result as same i checked with : ( id = id ) and in urls set <id> but result as the same and get 404 . but when i go to shell and test it said :>>> mohammad = Category.objects.all()
>>> mohammad
<QuerySet [<Category: elctronic>, <Category: oh my god>, <Category: spare Part>]>
>>> mohammad = Category.objects.filter(id=1)
>>> mohammad
<QuerySet [<Category: spare Part>]>

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in category_slug as two friends said that @Manjo Jadhav ,@JPG 
i used id instead of category_slug and it's working .
tnx for help friends.